# jquery Ajax split function is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to split the values using jquery Ajax. i retrieved the values from database like 234;345;567. now i want to show the first value. Please help me

```
var shipping = data.shxs;
var ship = shipping.split(';');
var status = shipping[0];
```

Comment: Can you post the issue you're having with the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `ship` variable for getting values and not `shipping`, see below code

```
var shipping = data.shxs;
var ship = shipping.split(';');//storing split array in ship
var status = ship[0];//use ship variable to get array elements
```

Comment: what do you mean by jquery ajax split function?

Comment: i m using jquery datatable to retrieve the database to display the values in table format. but i have more than 200 records so it takes more time to load so m using jquery ajax to retrieve the data

Answer (score 2):

you have correctly coded but when you are getting status you have wrong array because your array is in ship variable so you should bet status from ship array
i.e

```
var status=ship[0];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var shipping[] = data.shxs.split(';');

var status = shipping[0];
```

Comment: Please provide some text followed by your solution in order to make your answer more uderstandable to the community